# Doctrine 2 specific fields selected via querybuilder is not accessible using getter method

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

When I use doctrine 2 query builder as below to create a resultset:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->orm->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select("s.id","partial s.{id, name, user}","s.name","concat(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) fullName")
->add('from', 'Application\Entity\Schools s')
->leftJoin('s.user', 'u', 'WITH', 'u.id = s.user')
->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dd);
die;
```

It gives following data:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => DAV Public School
            )

        [id] => 1
        [name] => DAV Public School
        [fullName] => Manu Sharma
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Delhi Public School
            )

        [id] => 2
        [name] => Delhi Public School
        [fullName] => Vipul Sharma
    )
)
```

So when I try to fetch its value using getter method:

> $result->getName() doesn't work but I have to use $result[0]->getName().

and error says:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object

How to choose specific fields inside queryBuilder's select method so that main array values must be accessed using getter methods. Why its not working. Is there anything wrong with my select query.

What is the benefit if specific selected fields can't be accessed using getter method. I believe I'm doing something wrong but it doesn't strike my mind.

> Note: While using $result, I removed array_hydrate, that is I'm passing object and hence expecting getter methods to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is caused by adding additional fields to the SELECT clause. That's causing the result to put the object at index 0 to be able to add additional fields like `fullName` that you don't have in the entity to the result set.

As far as I understand, all you want is to have a method to get the full name of each user. Instead of solving that problem at the query level, you better just add a method to the `User` entity:

```
public function getFullName() {
    return sprintf('%s %s', $this->getFirstName(), $this->getLastName());
}
```

And then just select users the usual way:

```
SELECT u FROM User u
```

You can now get the full name of the first user the following way:

```
$result[0]->getFullName();
```

You don't need partial objects here. Partial objects have completely different use cases.